# How do I get gps track logs off a canmore gporter gp-102+ with linux / ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gps

I've got a [Canmore GP-102+ GPS](http://www.canmore.com.tw/productshow.php?selectub=&product_number=97) device. I can't figure how out to read the track logs from the device. They are in some kind of binary format with a .fit extension. I was hoping to use gpsbabel to convert them. A sample track log can be found [here](https://app.box.com/s/h1ct7sg3y86q7bhyp75h). I'm running Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Did you also find a way to read the POI files (no file extension) in the POI directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to convert the file with gpsbabel (version 1.4.4) on OS X 10.9.
Make sure to select the "Flexible and Interoperable Data Transfer Activity File" `.fit` as format for the input. On my first try I did not choose the input file format and gpsbabel didn't get the format right. I haven't changed any options for the conversion.

[here's the gpx version of your file](http://pastebin.com/6VjZ4dAk)

EDIT:
After looking through the change log of gpsbabel I now understand the problem. Packaged in the repositories of ubuntu is version 1.4.3 of gpsbabel which might not read the file correctly. On the project page you will only find sources as download for linux.

Alternative:
There are some websites that offer conversion of gps tracks. [This is an example](http://www.gpsies.com/convert.do) if you're happy with uploading all your tracks.

Comment: Michael, thank you! I downloaded and built the source for version 1.4.4 and it worked.

I also found [GPSVisualizer.com](http://gpsvisualizer.com) where you can upload the .fit file and it will plot it on a map.

There is also a [web version of gpsbabel](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/gpsbabel/gpsbabel_convert) that works well.

Comment: You're welcome, Matt. Now I got my hands on my Canmore device and I am experiencing some problems during conversion with gpsbabel (`fit: Definition message reserved bits not zero`). This is a known bug [see here for a patch](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=989851)